# I need code timed notifications on android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am currently developing an app which sends notifications at specific hours of the day. I can create an intent service, but I dont think it would work when the user is outside the app. So I need a service which works at specific times

Comment: you could use timer, but is dynamic periodic time? or fixed interval?

Comment: Use AlarmManager to send an alarm at a particular time.  If you need it to persist through reboots you may want to look at JobScheduler, which is a layer that uses AlarmManager and provides features like alarm persistence.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717528/how-to-send-the-firebase-notification-on-particular-time), I was using Firebase in my projects and it is super easy to implement...